# I can't pass through npm run check_txns --dir=minted

Tags: github, github-pages, nft, npm-run

I have ran npm run check_txns --dir=minted but I keep getting the error. Can you guys help me on it please?

moon@Jungs-MBP create-10k-nft-collection-2.0.0 % npm run check_txns --dir=minted

> 10k-collection-video@2.0.0 check_txns /Users/moon/Downloads/create-10k-nft-collection-2.0.0
> node utils/nftport/checkTxns %npm_config_dir%

Please specify the directory to check. Use "minted" or "revealed"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 10k-collection-video@2.0.0 check_txns: `node utils/nftport/checkTxns %npm_config_dir%`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the 10k-collection-video@2.0.0 check_txns script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I have ran npm run check_txns --dir=minted but I keep getting the error. Can you guys help me on it please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on package.json. Keep in mind the guy who explains in the video is using windows. If you have a Mac, you have to edit the package.json and switch the % symbol to $ symbol. Also you have to remove the $ symbol at the end of the parameters.
Your code should be like this:

```
"mint": "node utils/nftport/mint $npm_config_start $npm_config_end",
"reveal": "node utils/nftport/revealNFTs $npm_config_start $npm_config_end",
"check_txns": "node utils/nftport/checkTxns $npm_config_dir",
"refresh_os": "node utils/functions/refreshOpensea $npm_config_start
```

I hope it will work for you! :)

Comment: ...what "video"?

Comment: The who created the repo, explains in this video how to create the NFTs. I let you here it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaCgydeMu64